# C - Can't remove file in a folder wirh remove()

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to remove a file in a folder using C but it's crashing & throwing me some return value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char str[100];
    gets(str);
    strcat(str,"txt");

    fp1 = fopen(str,"r");
    fclose(fp1);

    remove(str);

    return 0;
}
```

This is not working. I'm using windows XP SP2 (32 bit) and also tried `system()` command in the C program, but  No help. Can anyone please help to fix this issue?

Comment: in strcat use strcat(str,".txt"); add . in txt

Comment: Never, ever, use `gets`. It is unsecure and has been removed from the C11 library for that fact. Use `fgets` and trim the `'\n'` from the end. If your professor wants you to use `gets`, drop the class now and go find another professor...

Comment: Finding sense in the unchecked `fopen` and `fclose` pair is proving difficult.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: What file are you trying to remove? One possibility is that you don't have enough permissions to remove that file.

Comment: Note that functions have return values, and code that ignores such return values and never checks for errors is bad code.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you are calling `fopen`, you are not reading anything from it. If you are attempting to use it as a check for the file's existence, there is no need, the return from `remove` will tell you whether the removal was successful.

For example, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define EXT ".txt"

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX 4096
#endif

int main (void) {

    char buf[PATH_MAX] = "";
    size_t len = 0;

    printf ("enter filename to delete (without .txt); ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin) || *buf == '\n') {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: EOF or invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    len = strlen (buf);         /* get length */
    if (buf[len - 1] == '\n')   /* check trailing '\n' */
        buf[--len] = 0;         /* overwrite with '\0' */
    else {
        /* handle error, input exceeded buf size */
        return 1;
    }

    strcat (buf, EXT);

    errno = 0;
    if (remove (buf) == -1)
        perror ("remove failed");
    else
        printf ("file: '%s' successfully removed.\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ls -al foobar.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Sep 17 06:35 foobar.txt

$ ./bin/rmfile
enter filename to delete (without .txt); foobar
file: 'foobar.txt' successfully removed.

$ ./bin/rmfile
enter filename to delete (without .txt); foobar
remove failed: No such file or directory
```

It works the same on Linux or DOS (you just need to define `PATH_MAX` on windows).

**Example Use/Output on Windows**

```
c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>cl /Wall /Ox /Febin\rmfile rmfile.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

rmfile.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:bin\rmfile.exe
rmfile.obj

c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>echo "test on Windoze" > foobar.txt

c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>dir foobar.txt
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 2045-D579

Directory of c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp

09/17/2017  06:56 AM                20 foobar.txt
            1 File(s)             20 bytes
            0 Dir(s)  20,235,399,168 bytes free

c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>bin\rmfile
enter filename to delete (without .txt); foobar
file: 'foobar.txt' successfully removed.

c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>bin\rmfile
enter filename to delete (without .txt); foobar
remove failed: No such file or directory
```

I guess if you are on windows, you should probably define the following at the top of the file to remove the `strcat` warning from the compiler:

```
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
```